# VSIS installer for outlook plug in using VSTO 4.0, Download VSTO 4.0 x86 and x64

Tags: vsto, nsis, outlook-addin

I am building a outlook plugin, for the installer, I decided to use NSIS install script. I have place a check for .Net 4.0 and I am able to download and install .Net Framework 4.0. But, I need some guidance regarding downloading and installing VSTO 4.0 runtime if not present on the client machine.

Basically runtimes that can be downloaded from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20479

I could always check for the presence of VSTO and detect OS and then using hard coded download location which is

for x64 
http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/3/9/F395E3C2-28A0-4F0D-9E20-FF4D1ADB08D8/vstor40_x64.exe

and 
for x86

http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/3/9/F395E3C2-28A0-4F0D-9E20-FF4D1ADB08D8/vstor40_x86.exe

Download and run the installer.

But, is there any better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it might help: [Microsoft Office 2010 Primary Interop Assemblies Bootstrapper Package 1.0 2010-9-7](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18249).